# ¿Cómo poner dos contraseñas a un solo usuario?

Tags: python, django

Soy nuevo en django y no logro dar con el clavo. Tengo un código en Django el cual autentica a un user a la hora de loguear, pero ademas quiero poder acceder a su cuenta (y la de todos los users) con una password general que solo conocera el admin.
Hasta ahora logre separar user de superusers, luego con el password ingresado del admin buscar si existe, y (es la idea) ingresar a la cuenta del usuario.

```
def user_login(request) :
    if request.method == "POST":
        # split users and superusers
        alluser = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False)
        allsuperuser = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)

        user_name = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        for sup in allsuperuser: #itero entre superusers
            #tomo el nombre del super user y lo combino con POST pasword
            superuser = auth.authenticate(username=sup.username,password=password)
            if superuser is not None:
                try:
                    if User.objects.get(username=user_name) is not None: #chequeo si existe el user
                        us = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
                        if us.is_superuser == False:
                            #aqui tomaria el user y loguearia (obviamente no puedo xq el pass tiene hash)
                            user = auth.authenticate(username=us.username,password=us.password)
                            auth.login(request, user)
                            return redirect('main')
                        else:
                            user = auth.authenticate(username=us.username,password=password)
                            auth.login(request, user)
                            return redirect('main')
                    else:
                        return render(request, 'auth-login.html', {'message': 'Credenciales invalidas'})
                except Exception:
                    return render(request, 'auth-login.html', {'message': 'Credenciales invalidas'})
                    
            else:
                user = auth.authenticate(username=user_name,password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return redirect('main')
                else:
                    return render(request, 'auth-login.html', {'message': 'Credenciales invalidas'})
    else:
        try:
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect('main')
            else:
                return render(request, "auth-login.html")        
        except Exception:
            return render(request, "auth-login.html", {'message': 'Credenciales invalidas'})
        return render(request, "auth-login.html")
```

No sé si voy por buen camino o hay una mejor forma, se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Comment: La pregunta no esta mal.. pero lleva a respuestas totalmente basadas en opiniones. En general, un superusuario no deberia loguearse como otro. Ya podria loguearse al ser superusuario y podria impersonar a cualquiera. Por lo tanto, no necesitarias multiples passwords....